# reducing file size of animated gif web banner

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif, cc-2015

I need to create a 728x180 animated banner for web ad,it has to be specifically weigh 40K, i used photos in creating the banner.  How can i reduce the weight without losing quality of the entire thing? right now it is 100+ kb and i can't do anything without destroying the quality.

Answer (score 4):

People want it all. Nice, big, smooth, cool, pretty, slick and 40k... You **can not** have it all.

To reduce a file size you need to choose something, maybe a cuple of things:

1. Reduce the dimensions.
2. Make the design flatter. Posterize the photos without using dither. https://www.google.com/search?q=photo+posterized
3. Reduce the total number of colors.
4. Reduce the total number of frames.
5. Reduce the area where the animation occur.
6. Save only the place where the animation happens, not the entire frame.
7. Be sure the total animation share the same palette. Sometimes you have different palettes on diferent frames.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this is going to help but have you tried reducing the number of colours? When you choose safe for web and on the top right select export as GIF you can choose the dither and number of colours. Reducing the number of colours can compromise a bit the quality of the image but it depends a lot on the kind of image you are using.

[image: 1]]

Don't forget to have a look at your gif at 100% zoom because that is how it will actually be seen on a webpage. I think that some imperfections you might be able to see at a higher zoom percentage won't really matter for the final outcome.

Comment: +1 just for saying to preview at 100%. Makes no sense to me when people zoom in to 800% then complain that it's pixelated/distorted/whatever.

Comment: You said this is for a web ad correct? Is it for yourself or for a client? Is the client the person who will zoom in 800% and say its pixelated?

Comment: Not my question, just a passer-by :)

Comment: Oh sorry did not notice that! :P
Still when I say to view it at 100% specially if it is an ad online, I cannot see people zooming in an ad. And sure you one can always hope to have a good quality image, specially because of all the media today we use to access online content like tablets and smartphones who make zoom in so easy. But in this case I think you can't be too hung up on quality when zooming in. Specially given the size they are asking. :)